# Using has() in a validation form

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

Hi guys so I'm trying to validate my form, one of the fields is an URL and my rules so far are:

```
 rules: {
                url: { required: true, url: true},
                name: { required: true },
                provider: { required: true }
            }
```

I would also like to use something like url:has(http) within the rules to check for the existence of a protocol. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkURL", function(value, element)
{
    var return_val = null;
    var message = null;
    var reg = /http(s?):\/\/www/;

    if (!reg.test($(element).val()))
    {
        return_val = false;
        message = "false message";
    }
    else
    {
        return_val = true;
        message = "";
    }
    jQuery.validator.messages.checkURL = message;
    return return_val;
}, jQuery.validator.messages.checkURL);
```

Use it as

```
rules:
{
    url: { required: true, checkURL: true},
    name: { required: true },
    provider: { required: true }
}
```

Comment: so adding OR check in that IF statement would sort that out?

Comment: Could you please clarify why it wouldn't be a good way to do it? I'd like to understand what I'm doing while I'm doing it. Thanks.

Comment: @Mantas it not good practice because it will create unnecessary check conditions...performance vise its not good but its works too...if having single check do the trick then we do not need to check it again

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for such a quick and clear response. Still a junior dev learning to use regex and stuff that improves performance!

Comment: @Mantas dont worry in near future you will be the great developer too because everyone has started from `0`